# How can I call two functions for different percentage of the total requests received?

Tags: python, random, python-requests, probability

I have a particular request and want to call two functions f1 and f2. I want to call the function f1 for 95% of the total requests and f2 for the remaining 5% requests. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: `f2` for *which* 5% of the requests? What is the rule that says when to use f2?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel based on a random number basically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the random module

```
import random


def request_handler():
    test = random.random() # random number in [0, 1)
    if test < 0.95:        # 95% of the time, the number will be < 0.95
        return f1()        
    return f2()            # rest of the time, it'll be higher
```